# How to translate onion sites in a tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, google, darknet

Google translate doesn't accept onion addresses, and I'd rather not pass my text through Google anyway. How then, can I translate onion websites in tor browser, in a way which is preferably both convenient and secure?